# Changing SRP-6a message order

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs, srp

In SRP-6a, the public key $B$ of the server is normally sent after receiving the public key of the client $A$. Is it okay to send $B$ and $s$ after the client sends its username $I$, but before the client sends $A$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's okay.

This is actually mentioned in passing in the [SRP 6 design paper](http://srp.stanford.edu/srp6.ps). Previous versions used a random $u$ where an attacker who saw (or could predict) it before revealing $A$ could compute $A = g^a v^{-u}$ and use this to effectively cancel out the long term secret. With $u$ derived from a hash, even if the attacker saw $B$, the dependence of $u$ on $A$ means that they would need to break the hash function to be able to find a suitable $a$/$A$ for an attack.